# How do I rotate a previously dragged SVG object using JavaScript and Raphael?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, svg, raphael, rotation

I'm using the Raphael library to rotate and drag an image.  I have it correctly dragging and I have a button that correctly rotates it 90 degrees each time it's pressed.  However I'm having a problem when I rotate the image, drag it, and then try to rotate it again.

The only elements in the HTML are the div to hold the Raphael canvas and the button that rotates the image.  The JavaScript is here:

```
var gboard;
var piece;

window.onload = function () 
{
    gboard = Raphael("gameboard", 800, 500);    
    // piece = gboard.rect(100, 100, 50, 50).attr({fill: "#0CF", "fill-opacity": 1, stroke: "none", cursor: "move"});
    piece = gboard.image("piece.gif", 100, 100, 50, 50).attr({cursor: "move"});
    piece.drag(dragMove, dragStart, dragStop);  
    var angle = 0;

    document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function () {
        angle += 90;
        var cx = piece.attr('x') + 25;
        var cy = piece.attr('y') + 25;
        piece.animate({transform: "R" + angle + ", " + cx + ", " + cy + ""}, 500, "<>");
        // piece.transform("R90," + cx + "," + cy);
    };

}

// Set up the object for dragging
function dragStart() 
{
    this.ox = this.attr("x");
    this.oy = this.attr("y");
}

// Clean up after dragging ends
function dragStop() {}

/**
 * Handle the moving of objects when dragging 
 * Check the current angle to compensate for rotated coordinate system.
 */
function dragMove(dx, dy) 
{
    var angle = getAngle(this._['deg']);
    if (angle == 90)
        this.attr({x: this.ox + dy, y: this.oy - dx});
    else if (angle == 180)
        this.attr({x: this.ox - dx, y: this.oy - dy});
    else if (angle == 270)
        this.attr({x: this.ox - dy, y: this.oy + dx});
    else // angle == 0
        this.attr({x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy});
}

/** 
 * Get the simplified equivalent angle (0 <= angle <= 360) for the given angle. 
 *
 * @param deg   The angle in degrees
 * @return  The equivalent angle between 0 and 360
 */
function getAngle(deg)
{
    if (deg % 360 == 0)
        return 0;   
    else if (deg < 0)
    {
        while (deg < 0)
            deg += 360;
    }
    else if (deg > 360)
    {
        while (deg > 360)
            deg -= 360;
    }

    return deg;
}
```

Comment: I think I might have created a solution for a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8190476/981898)

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by re-applying all transformations when a value changes.

http://alias.io/raphael/free_transform/

Source: https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.FreeTransform

Comment: Nice solution. +1 for brilliant example.

Comment: @Elbert Alias this plugin can rotate and resize normal div or img?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manipulating the position with the x/y attributes and the rotation with a transform, you can use the transform tool to handle both, simplifying your project quite a bit.

Since we're using a capital 'T' in the translation, which ignores previous translation commands in the same string, we no longer have to worry about the current angle when dragging.

```
var gboard, 
    piece;

gboard = Raphael("gameboard", 800, 500);    

var angle = 0,
    x = 100,
    y = 100;

//note that this now starts at 0,0 and is immediately translated to 100,100
piece = gboard.image("piece.gif", 0, 0, 50, 50).attr({cursor: "move", transform: "R" + angle + "T" + x + "," + y });

piece.drag(dragMove, dragStart, dragStop);

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function () {  
  angle += 90;
  piece.animate({transform: "R" + angle + "T" + x + "," + y}, 500, "<>");
};

// Set up the object for dragging
function dragStart() 
{
    this.ox = x;
    this.oy = y;
}

// Clean up after dragging ends
function dragStop() {}

//Since we're using a capital 'T' in the translation, which ignores previous translation commands in the same string, we no longer have to worry about the current angle here    
function dragMove(dx, dy) {
  x = this.ox + dx;
  y = this.oy + dy;
  piece.attr({ transform: "R" + angle + "T" + x + "," + y });
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CUUZ6/2/)

Comment: This is a nice simple solution

Answer (score 0):

Curious; it looks like the rotation actually alters the x and y values. So if you rotate 90 degrees, moving the box 100 pixels to the right actually moves it 100 pixels **up**, which is then translated as being to the right. This is throwing off the cx and cy values, which determine the point around which to rotate the box.

To see what I mean, rotate once, then drag the box while watching the X and Y values in the inspector.

I can see two ways to fix it: you can either do the math to recalculate the "real" x and y on every rotation, or you can keep track of the x and y on your own by attaching data attributes (which is what I would recommend). Good luck!

Comment: I added tracking to the image's position with two global
variables `tx` and `ty`.  Then before I rotate I copy `tx`, `ty` to
`image.attr('x')` and `image.attr('y')` and calculate `cx`, `cy` from `tx`, `ty`.  Unfortunately this doesn't make any difference.  What am I missing?

I edited the test page above with what I described.