# Drag, drop and shape rotation with Raphael JS

Tags: drag-and-drop, raphael, rotation

I'm using RaphaelJS 2.0 to create several shapes in a div.  Each shape needs to be able to be dragged and dropped within the bounds of the div, independently.  Upon double clicking a shape, that shape needs to rotate 90 degrees.  It may then be dragged and dropped and rotated again.

I've loaded some code onto fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/QRZMS/.  It's basically this:

```
    window.onload = function () {

        var angle = 0;

        var R = Raphael("paper", "100%", "100%"),
            shape1 = R.rect(100, 100, 100, 50).attr({ fill: "red", stroke: "none" }),
            shape2 = R.rect(200, 200, 100, 50).attr({ fill: "green", stroke: "none" }),
            shape3 = R.rect(300, 300, 100, 50).attr({ fill: "blue", stroke: "none" }),
            shape4 = R.rect(400, 400, 100, 50).attr({ fill: "black", stroke: "none" });
        var start = function () {
            this.ox = this.attr("x");
            this.oy = this.attr("y");
        },
        move = function (dx, dy) {
            this.attr({ x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy });
        },
        up = function () {

        };
        R.set(shape1, shape2, shape3, shape4).drag(move, start, up).dblclick(function(){
            angle -= 90;
            shape1.stop().animate({ transform: "r" + angle }, 1000, "<>");
        });


    }
```

The drag and drop is working and also one of the shapes rotates on double click.  However, there are two issues/questions:

1. How can I attach the rotation onto each shape automatically without having to hard-code each item reference into the rotate method?  I.e. I just want to draw the shapes once, then have them all automatically exposed to the same behaviour, so they can each be dragged/dropped/rotated independently without having to explicitly apply that behaviour to each shape.
2. After a shape has been rotated, it no longer drags correctly - as if the drag mouse movement relates to the original orientation of the shape rather than updating when the shape is rotated.  How can I get this to work correctly so that shapes can just be dragged and rotated many times, seamlessley?

Many thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've tried several times to wrap my head around the new transform engine, to no avail. So, I've gone back to first principles.

I've finally managed to correctly drag and drop an object thats undergone several transformations, after trying to work out the impact of the different transformations - t,T,...t,...T,r,R etc...

So, here's the crux of the solution

```
var ox = 0;
var oy = 0;

function drag_start(e) 
{
};


function drag_move(dx, dy, posx, posy) 
{


   r1.attr({fill: "#fa0"});

   //
   // Here's the interesting part, apply an absolute transform 
   // with the dx,dy coordinates minus the previous value for dx and dy
   //
   r1.attr({
    transform: "...T" + (dx - ox) + "," + (dy - oy)
   });

   //
   // store the previous versions of dx,dy for use in the next move call.
   //
   ox = dx;
   oy = dy;
}


function drag_up(e) 
{
   // nothing here
}
```

That's it. Stupidly simple, and I'm sure it's occurred to loads of people already, but maybe someone might find it useful.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/3DBWM/) for you to play around with.

... and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/Xy4zp/) is a working solution for the initial question.

Comment: That's great, thanks for persisting amadan - I really appreciate it.  To be honest, my initial forray into Raphael hasn't been good.  The documentation is brief at best (e.g. try to find anything that explains how to use the matrix part of the transform method) and there's so little support on the web it just makes things painful for a newby like me.  Perhaps it's just that v2 is so new and so different, or maybe it really is aimed at serious javascript heavyweights who can pull the source apart, who knows.  Thanks again though, this has really helped and I totally appreciate it!

Comment: Dan, you've got to consider what the Raphael library is trying to do. It's exposing the SVG (and VML) capabilities of the browser to javascript. As such much of what it does is a direct exposure of the underlying SVG element. This is exactly what the transformation piece is. If you're looking for information about how they work, and in particular matrix transformations, you need to google for "SVG matrix transformation" as opposed to "Raphael matrix transformation". Try http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Matrix_Algebra or http://www.mecxpert.de/svg/transform.html

Comment: Fiddle doesn't work in FF7. After the first drag, the relative location of shape and mouse goes out of sync.

Comment: OrangeDog, Can you elaborate? I've tested on IE8.0.6001, chrome 15.0.874, and Firefox 8.0, and it appears to be working fine.

Comment: OrangeDog, You are right, he forgot to reset drag start position in the fiddle example, just replace drag start with this and it works great: function drag_start(e) {
    ox = 0;
    oy = 0;
};

Comment: Good catch Hogberg. In my defense, I tested with the second fiddle, the worked solution. In that one I reset ox and oy on the mouseup function. I've updated the example now.So, horray - we were both right. Have and upvote.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the drag/rotate issue by re-applying all transformations when a value changes. I created a plugin for it.

https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.FreeTransform

Demo here:

http://alias.io/raphael/free_transform/

Answer (score 3):

As amadan suggests, it's usually a good idea to create functions when multiple things have the same (initial) attributes/properties. That is indeed the answer to your first question. As for the second question, that is a little more tricky.

When a Rapheal object is rotated, so is the coordinate plane. For some reason, dmitry and a few other sources on the web seem to agree that it's the correct way to implement it. I, like you, disagree. I've not managed to find an all round good solution but I did mange to create a work around. I'll briefly explain and then show the code.

- Create a custom attribute to store the current state of rotation
- Depending on that attribute you decide how to handle the move.

Providing that you are only going to be rotating shapes by 90 degrees (if not it becomes a lot more difficult) you can determine how the coordinates should be manipulated.

```
var R = Raphael("paper", "100%", "100%");

//create the custom attribute which will hold the current rotation of the object {0,1,2,3}
R.customAttributes.rotPos = function (num) {
    this.node.rotPos = num;
};

var shape1 = insert_rect(R, 100, 100, 100, 50, { fill: "red", stroke: "none" });
var shape2 = insert_rect(R, 200, 200, 100, 50, { fill: "green", stroke: "none" });
var shape3 = insert_rect(R, 300, 300, 100, 50, { fill: "blue", stroke: "none" });
var shape4 = insert_rect(R, 400, 400, 100, 50, { fill: "black", stroke: "none" });

//Generic insert rectangle function
function insert_rect(paper,x,y, w, h, attr) {
    var angle = 0;
    var rect = paper.rect(x, y, w, h);  
    rect.attr(attr);

    //on createion of the object set the rotation position to be 0
    rect.attr({rotPos: 0});

    rect.drag(drag_move(), drag_start, drag_up);

    //Each time you dbl click the shape, it gets rotated. So increment its rotated state (looping round 4)
    rect.dblclick(function(){
        var pos = this.attr("rotPos");
        (pos++)%4;
        this.attr({rotPos: pos});
        angle -= 90;
        rect.stop().animate({transform: "r" + angle}, 1000, "<>");
    });

    return rect;  
}

//ELEMENT/SET Dragger functions.
function drag_start(e) {
    this.ox = this.attr("x");
    this.oy = this.attr("y");
};


//Now here is the complicated bit
function drag_move() {
    return function(dx, dy) {

        //default position, treat drag and drop as normal
        if (this.attr("rotPos") == 0) {
          this.attr({x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy});
        }
        //The shape has now been rotated -90
        else if (this.attr("rotPos") == 1) {

            this.attr({x:this.ox-dy, y:this.oy + dx});
        }           
        else if (this.attr("rotPos") == 2) {
            this.attr({x: this.ox - dx, y: this.oy - dy});
        }
        else if (this.attr("rotPos") == 3) {
             this.attr({x:this.ox+dy, y:this.oy - dx});

        }      
    }
};

function drag_up(e) {
}
```

I can't really think of clear concise way to explain how the drag_move works. I think it's probably best that you look at the code and see how it works. Basically, you just need to work out how the x and y variables are now treated from this new rotated state. Without me drawing lots of graphics I'm not sure I could be clear enough. (I did a lot of turning my head sideways to work out what it should be doing).

There are a few drawbacks to this method though:

- It only works for 90degree rotations (a huge amount more calculations would be needed to do 45degrees, nevermind any given degree)
- There is a slight movement upon drag start after a rotation. This is because the drag takes the old x and y values, which have been rotated. This isn't a massive problem for this size of shape, but bigger shapes you will really start to notice shapes jumping across the canvas.

I'm assuming the reason that you are using transform is that you can animate the rotation. If this isn't necessary then you could use the `.rotate()` function which always rotates around the center of the element and so would eliminate the 2nd drawback I mentioned.

This isn't a complete solution, but it should definitely get you going along the correct path. I would be interested to see a full working version.

I've also created a version of this on jsfiddle which you can view here: http://jsfiddle.net/QRZMS/3/

Good luck.

Comment: I've pretty much got to the same point as you describe above. In fact, you're getting the same results I am. moving without rotation works, a first rotation works, but subsequent rotations are increasingly incorrect. It's nice to get confirmation though. Have an upvote.

Comment: Thanks Adam. We're getting there, but it's disappointingly difficult to achieve this kind of thing with Raphael.  I'm actually wondering if I've chosen the right tool for the job here, as I need to do some relatively complex stuff with dragging and dropping of objects.  If it's so difficult to achieve this, then I think the other stuff is going to be way too hard.  I'll persist for now though, so thanks for your kind efforts!

Answer (score 1):

I usually create an object for my shape and write the event handling into the object.

```
function shape(x, y, width, height, a)
{
  var that = this;
  that.angle = 0;
  that.rect = R.rect(x, y, width, height).attr(a);

  that.rect.dblclick(function() {
      that.angle -= 90;
      that.rect.stop().animate({
          transform: "r" + that.angle }, 1000, "<>");
  });
  return that;
}
```

In the above, the constructor not only creates the rectangle, but sets up the double click event.

One thing to note is that a reference to the object is stored in "that". This is because the "this" reference changes depending on the scope. In the dblClick function I need to refer to the **rect** and **angle** values from my object, so I use the stored reference **that.rect** and **that.angle**

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vPSuR/) (updated from a slightly dodgy previous instance)

There may be better ways of doing what you need, but this should work for you.

Hope it help,

Nick

---

Addendum: Dan, if you're **really** stuck on this, and can live without some of the things that Raphael2 gives you, I'd recommend moving back to Raphael 1.5.x. Transforms were just added to Raphael2, the rotation/translation/scale code is entirely different (and easier) in 1.5.2.

Look at me, updating my post, hoping for karma...

Comment: Thanks Nick.  I'll have a look into this, but on initial inspection of that fiddle page, the shapes still behave really weirdly.  They seem to spin by different increments and the drag-n-drop is all over the place.

Comment: I'm all embarrassed.. There was a typo in my fiddle. angle should be part of the object and each instance get incremented separately. I've updated the fiddle and it should work correctly now. Blame it on having multiple browsers open :(

Comment: Fiddle is being a bit difficult :( try this link instead http://jsfiddle.net/vPSuR/

Comment: Actually, it turns out DnD works the first time and then goes a bit mad. I withdraw my terrible solution, and apologise for wasting your time.

Comment: Haha, no worries Nick - that's for trying!

Comment: If it helps, the drag and drop is getting affected by the rotation. All translations, rotations etc. are part of the new transform() architecture, and they concatenate, producing strange results. If you rotate one of my rectangles the direction of the drag rotates as well. I still haven't gotten my head around how to safely apply a transform to an already transformed object without it blowing up.

Comment: Yeah, that's the big issue.  The transform and drag events seem to bind to the modified shape, which creates some undesirable effects.

Comment: Here's a bug that was raised against it, and Dmetri's comment. It's correct behaviour (which is probably true, but counter intuitive). DnD and rotation aren't friends in 2.0 :(   https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/102

Comment: final thought for now.... http://jsfiddle.net/vPSuR/  I've munged with the move function to alter the modification to the rectangle position based on the rotation applied, which works a little better. the rotation doesn't remain centred on the rect though, so it's not a solution. I might look at this again tonight

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a ElbertF library, you can transform Cartesian Coordinates in Polar Coordinates.

After you must add or remove the angle and transform again in Cartesian Coordinate.

We can see this example with a rect rotate in rumble and moved.

**HTML**

```
<div id="foo">

</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var paper = Raphael(40, 40, 400, 400); 
var c = paper.rect(40, 40, 40, 40).attr({ 
    fill: "#CC9910", 
    stroke: "none", 
    cursor: "move" 
}); 
c.transform("t0,0r45t0,0");

var start = function () { 
    this.ox = this.type == "rect" ? this.attr("x") : this.attr("cx");
    this.oy = this.type == "rect" ? this.attr("y") : this.attr("cy");
}, 

move = function (dx, dy) { 
    var r = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2));
    var ang = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
    ang = ang - Math.PI/4;
    dx = r * Math.cos(ang);
    dy = r * Math.sin(ang);

    var att = this.type == "rect" ? { x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy} : { cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy };
    this.attr(att);
}, 

up = function () { 
}; 

c.drag(move, start, up);?
```

**DEMO**
http://jsfiddle.net/Ef83k/74/

Answer (score 0):

my first thought was to use getBBox(false) to capture the x,y coordinates of the object after transform, then removeChild() the original Raphael obj from the canvas, then redraw the object using the coordinate data from getBBox( false ).  a hack but i have it working.

one note though: since the object the getBBox( false ) returns is the CORNER coordinates ( x, y) of the object you need to calculate the center of the re-drawn object by doing ...
  x = box['x'] + ( box['width'] / 2 );
  y = box['y'] + ( box['height'] / 2 );

where 
box = shapeObj.getBBox( false );

another way to solve the same problem