# Very Strange: Every other time an array is updated its values are screwed up

Tags: arrays, loops, mouse, raphael

You can see the code there: http://jsfiddle.net/jocose/CkL5F/901/
(double click on the box and move your mouse)

NOTE:  This is a simplified example that is part of a larger system.  My ultimate goal is to manipulate individual vertices of a path.

**Update:  I crunched the numbers and the math actually apears to be correct.  What I want to do is calculate the offset from each point to the mouse, and then move that point to the mouses position + the offset.
So if I have a mouse of 224 then  224-103 = 121 then I add: 121+224=345
These creates a cycle of ups and downs that I am seeing.  I don't know why these is stumping me so badly, any help would be much appreciated.**

I need to manually update a Raphael path element.

To do this I convert an absolute path into an array using Raphael great built in function "parsePathString"

I then loop through that array and modify the values based off the mouse position.

The update is done to the X values only, and is in real time; called each time the mouse moves.

When the element moves it flickers back and forth between the correct position and some anomalous one.

I have no clue why its doing this.  I have spent almost 5 hours trying to figure this out and I'm officially stuck.

Here is a sample of the result where you can see the values jumping around:

```
MOUSE224 
M,103.676287 
MOUSE225 
M,346.323713 
MOUSE227 
M,107.676287 
MOUSE228 
M,348.323713 12
MOUSE228 
M,107.676287 
MOUSE229 
M,350.323713
MOUSE231 
M,111.67S287 
MOUSE232 
M,3S2.323713
MOUSE233 
M,113.676287
MOUSE233 
M,3S2.323713
```

Comment: Am I right in assuming that this is a simplified example and there's a reason why a transformation won't do it for you?

Comment: Yes you are, this is part of a more complex system in which I need to do exactly this.  My goal is to manipulate individual vertices on a path in a specific way.  This is just a test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my version of your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/KHbWh/) modified to do what I think you need. At least, it seems to work. It's the same type of problem I had to fix for the Raphael 2 transformations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8190476/981898).

Basically, in your mousemove, I've changed mx to be a calculation of the offset between where your mouse is now and where it was the last time mousemove was called. Your move() function now only has to add this value to the x-coords.

Hope this helps you out somewhat

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  This site never ceases to maaze me.  Have a look at what you helped me create:  http://jsfiddle.net/jocose/CkL5F/1098/

Drag the box to the middle, double click, and move your mouse.

Comment: glad I could help. If you're happy with the answer, upvote. Remember, karma counts!

Comment: the problem still exist to some extent. you can see it manifest on the first try to move the mouse.

Comment: @user1372122, it is common courtesy (and beneficial to the community, and yourself) to accept correct answers. please do.