# how to get the current circle position in raphael on dragend

Tags: jquery, html, raphael

I'm messing around with `Raphael.js` and got the following problem.
I have a draggable circle (ellipse) which should rotate `+15` or `-15` degree on button click around its center point.

```
var angle = 0;
function rotateLeft(e) {
    angle += 15;
    circle.animate( {transform: "r" + angle}, 500);
}   

function rotateRight(e) {
    angle -= 15;
    circle.animate( {transform: "r" + angle}, 500);
}               

$('#left').on('click', this, rotateRight);
$('#right').on('click', this, rotateLeft);
```

which works so far if the `circle` was not dragged on another position before. If the circle was already dragged, it animates around its center point, but also animates to the point where the drag started.

**What i want to is, that after drag the current position saves when rotating the circle.**

I've uploaded the files, so you can have a [LOOK](http://work.mach-parat.de/nico_samples/suchspiel/)

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Note: My drag-code refers to this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115713/drag-drop-and-shape-rotation-with-raphael-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common cause of heartburn with Raphael transformations, since they overwrite one another routinely. Try this: Keep `ox` and `oy` as variables representing the current rest position of the oval, and translate the shape each time you rotate it. (Also, rotate it each time you translate it):

I messed with the code a bit to make it fit in a jsFiddle without jQuery, but concept is identical:

```
var docwidth = 500;
var docheight = 500;
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, docheight, docwidth);
var circle = paper.ellipse(180, 100, 50, 80); 
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
circle.attr("stroke", "#000");
circle.attr("opacity", "0.4");

function drawCircle(e) {    
    var $random = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;

    if($random == 1) {
        var circle = paper.ellipse(e.pageX, e.pageY, 20, 50); 
    }

    if($random == 2) {
        var circle = paper.ellipse(e.pageX, e.pageY, 50, 80); 
    }

    if($random == 3) {
        var circle = paper.ellipse(e.pageX, e.pageY, 100, 100); 
    }
    circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
    circle.attr("stroke", "#000");
    circle.attr("opacity", "0.4");
}

// DRAG
var ox = 0;
var oy = 0;

var current_x, current_dy;

function drag_start() {}

//Now here is the complicated bit
function drag_move(dx, dy, posx, posy) {
    //console.log(dx, dy, posx, posy);
    circle.attr({
        fill: "#fa0"
    });

    // keep ox and oy at the original location for the duration 
    // of the drag and just us dx/dy 
    circle.attr({
        transform: "T" + (ox + dx) + "," + (oy + dy) + "R" + angle
    });

    // save net dag coordinates -- we'll need them.
    current_x = dx;
    current_y = dy;
}


function drag_up(e) {
    // don't forget to reset the original positions.
    ox += current_x;
    oy += current_y;
    console.log(ox, oy);
}

circle.drag(drag_move, drag_start, drag_up);

// ROTATION
var angle = 0;
function rotateLeft(e) {
    angle += 15;
    circle.animate( {transform: "T" + ox + "," + oy + "R" + angle}, 500);
}   

function rotateRight(e) {
    angle -= 15;
    circle.animate( {transform: "T" + ox + "," + oy + "R" + angle}, 500);
}               

document.getElementById('left').onclick = rotateRight;
document.getElementById('right').onclick = rotateLeft;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chriswilsondc/Pq9qx/1/

In general, think of each transformation as starting from scratch. I generally avoid the "..." syntax as well, since it's so difficult to debug in cases like this.

Comment: wow, thank you very much! This is exactly what i wanted and it works flawless. Also thanks you the explanation comments for a better understanding. But has it a special reason using purely JavaScript for the buttons?

Comment: No reason at all, I just couldn't remember how to load two different libraries in jsfiddle.